# Configure expo notifications for push notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I have 2 apps and I implemented expo push notification and everything was fine, but in the other one it asked me for the experienceid as a prop to Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
experienceId: "@name/slug,
});

and when trying to send a notification it gives me this error: InvalidCredentials: Unable to retrieve the FCM server key for the recipient's app. Make sure you have provided a server key as directed by the Expo FCM documentation.

I dont want to use FCM, i want to use expo push api.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The Expo Push API uses FCM for Android, and while it's not necessary to configure it for Expo Go (this is done already for the Expo Go app), when you deploy your standalone app you will need to have it configured for FCM. More information here: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/